# Draw Child Control beyond Parent boundaries?

Tags: delphi, controls, vcl

I' making a custom inplace editor for a `dbGridEH` descendant which will show instead of the regular inplace editor. The inplace editor is larger in size than a cell. If it shows over the last cell in a row its right part gets clipped.
I'd like to prevent parts of the inplace editor from being сlipped, so it will be fully painted even beyond parent / form boundaries, the way popup menus do.

how do I do that?

Comment: In order to do something like this you need to use seperate standalone window for your inplace editor.

Comment: @SilverWarior, a separate form/dialog or a separate TWinControl?

Comment: I think this laregly depends on what capabilities do you require from inplace editor. If the inplace editor does have rich structure (buttons, input fields, etc) then you might wanna use form becouse this way you get ability to visualy design the inplace editor look. Using of dialogs might not e est idea since they are usually modal and therefore prevents interaction with the rest of your application UI while they are shown. But if your inplace editor is just an enlarged input box or something similar then you might want to use on of the base control classes like TCustomEdit for instance.